# Shot rotation for WoW Beast Master Hunter

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to know which shot rotations are good for a Beast Master Hunter in World of Warcraft.

If it matters, I'm level 80 and I play in a non PvP server, so I want the shot rotation for dungeons basically.

Comment: Rotations are a thing of the past. What you are looking for is a shot priority list.

Comment: @dpatchery Could you explain more please? I'm new to WoW and this is my first character (I have others but all under level 15).

Comment: @dpatchery means that because Hunters now have a unique resource mechanic, focus, the old style of a hunter "rotation", i.e., press these attacks, in this order, until the mob dies, is obsolete. Nowadays, you are limited by Focus, which is a lot more interesting than the binary "have mana/ no mana" of days past. This means you cannot simply use a "rotation", as your focus levels are changing too rapidly to make any long-term, consistent "rotation" possible. Instead, you want to use the ability that has the most benefit to your DPS, at any given moment, i.e., a shot priority system.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Exactly. You said it better than I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to aim for is: Focus Fire -> Kill Shot (if available) -> Kill Command -> Arcane Shot -> Cobra Shot.

I would also recommend not going BM for levelling. The Marksman talent tree (along with a few talents from BM) will allow you to DPS non-stop while in dungeons.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are some great guides on http://www.warcrafthuntersunion.com/cataclysm-hunter-guides/ for all the Hunter specs.

You can find the Beast Mastery guide specifically at http://www.warcrafthuntersunion.com/2010/11/cataclysm-bm-hunter-shot-rotation/, as well as information about the ideal talents to use and the best glyphs.

The shot priority for BM is Focus Fire > Kill Shot > Kill Command > Arcane Shot > Cobra Shot.  You want to try to pop Focus Fire when your pet has 5 stacks of Frenzy.  The other thing to think about is proper use of Bestial Wrath and Fervor.